# CDN Tax Receipts - Cover Letter

Tags: receipts

We currently use "CDN Tax Receipts" to generate our tax receipts. I am wondering if it is possible to also have a cover letter used when this tax receipt is generated?  My hope would be that when I print the PDF tax receipt, it would also generate a letter, with pre-determined information.  Is this possible?

Comment: I haven't tried this but you might be able to do it with hook_cdntaxreceipts_writeReceipt. You'd need to do something like write your cover page to the $pdf and then at the end call $pdf->AddPage() and return FALSE.